# Single class in stylesheet not get designed

Tags: html, css

I have around 10 classes in my stylesheet and every one works great, except one.

My .pbild does not get designed, i repeat everything else gets designed how i define.

In my stylesheet is no error I am pretty sure.

**CSS**

```
h2 {
   margin: 0 auto;
}

p {
  margin-top: 0.5%;
}

#header {
  text-align: center;
}

#register {
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 0.5%;
  width: 10%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#login {
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 0.5%;
  width: 10%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.wrap h3{
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

#navi {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

#navi li {
  margin: 3%;
  display: inline;
}

.navipt {
  background-color: darkgrey;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0.5%;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

#navi a:link{
  color: white;
}

#navi a:visited{
  color: white;
}

#navi a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#uploadform {
  margin-top: 2%;
}

#uploadform h3 {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

#uploadimage {
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 0.5%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.info {
  margin-top: 1.5%;
}

#myuploads {
  margin-top: 1.5%;
}

.pbild {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

**PHP**

```
if(isset($_SESSION["username"])){
    $hash = hash('sha224', $_SESSION["username"]);

    $dir = "uploads/$hash";

    $alledateien = scandir($dir);

    foreach ($alledateien as $datei)
    {
        if ($datei != "." && $datei != "..")
        {
            echo "<div class='pbild'><img src='$dir/$datei'><br/><form action='deleteimg.php'><input class='deleteimg' type='submit' value='delete'></form></div>";
        }
    }
}else{
    header("Location: ../index.php");
}
?>
```

I really can not figure out why.

Chrome Dev Tool Snippet:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/F85QT.png

Thanks

Comment: I might be missing something, but it may help if you can show us the rest of your CSS file; there may be some conflict somewhere?

Comment: Define "not considered". Are you being redirected to index.php? I for one have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: @Fred-ii- i was just away from keyboard. What do you mean "redirected to index.php"?

Comment: @Ant my stylesheet is good to go i think.

Comment: like I said; you didn't describe what is not working/considered. You have conditional statements. When you run this, is the header kicking in? describe the problem you are having in detail. Otherwise, I'd have to setup a script for this to "maybe" see what is happening on my end.

Comment: This is most likely not a php problem then and the tag for it should be removed. Add `!important` to the rules and see what happens. Other than that, I don't know how I can be of further help. Wait for someone else to hopefully shed some light on this and see the answer below and post a comment under it. What should be the result and what result are you getting now, is the question.

Comment: @Fred-ii- How i said, everything in my script works, just one class (.pbild) does not get designed.

Comment: @Fred-ii- since i've tried to set is as !important the div doesnt get it's parent design. Neither if i unset !important.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure if the html of that div exists in the browser's html section. May be your div does not exist in the browser.

Comment: My div exists in the HTML section.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for help at all,
but i've found the solution myself.

I have just removed the `<div>` around my `<img>` and gave the `<img>` the class `.pbild`. Now it get's designed how it should.

**BEFORE**

```
echo "<div class='pbild'><img src='$dir/$datei'><br/><form action='deleteimg.php'><input class='deleteimg' type='submit' value='delete'></form></div>";
```

**AFTER**

```
echo "<img class='pbild' src='$dir/$datei'><br/><form action='deleteimg.php'><input class='deleteimg' type='submit' value='delete'></form>";
```

**I still dont know why it was not working before, if you know the answer feel free to comment.**

Comment: This could be a caching issue, perhaps the updated CSS file had not been loaded?

Comment: This was not the fault, i have tested to design other elements and it worked great.